# Eigenvalues gone wild

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I added some significant details to this problem, as it was apparently not clear to everyone what I want to know:

This is a question about convergence of eigenvalues which essentially came up in studying the spectrum of St.-Liouville operators. 
We want to look at matrices that agree in most of their entries and want to investigate whether this implies convergence of the eigenvalues.

We start with two matrices $$ A_1:=\left[ \begin {array}{cc}  3.5&- 0.5\\ - 0.5& 0.75
\end {array} \right] $$ with eigenvalues
$$\lambda_{1,1} := 0.661912511160047 \quad \lambda_{1,2}:=3.58808748883995  $$ and the matrix
$$ B_1:=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc}  3.5&- 0.5&-1/4\,\sqrt {2}
\\ - 0.5& 0.25&-1/2\,\sqrt {2}\\ -
1/4\,\sqrt {2}&-1/2\,\sqrt {2}&- 0.5\end {array} \right] 
$$
with eigenvalues $$\mu_{1,0}:=-0.9958877876 \quad \mu_{1,1}:= 0.6554756723 \quad  \mu_{1,2}:=3.590412115.$$

We observe that $\lambda_{1,1} \approx \mu_{1,1} $ and $\lambda_{1,2} \approx \mu_{1,2}$.

Now, we extend our matrices to larger dimensions, denoting them as $A_{i},B_{i}$ ,in the following way:
So we get $A_i$ from $A_1$ by doing the following:

(i) we use $A_1$ as the $A_i[n-1:n,n-1:n]$ submatrix of $A_i$. The elements down the diagonal are found from bottom to top by successive iterations in steps of two:
 So $A_i(n-2,n-2) = A_i(n-1,n-1) + 5$,

$A_i(n-3,n-3) = A_i(n-2,n-2) + 7$

$A_i(n-4,n-4) = A_i(n-3,n-3) + 9$ and so on.

(ii)Down the first subdiagonal all entries are $-0.5$ and

(iii)down the subsubdiagonal all entries are $-0.25$.

All other entries are zero!

For the $B_i$ we use the same extension, but use the different basis matrix

$$ B_i[n-2:n,n-2:n]:=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc}  3.5&- 0.5&-1/4\,\sqrt {2}
\\ - 0.5& 0.25&-1/2\,\sqrt {2}\\ -
1/4\,\sqrt {2}&-1/2\,\sqrt {2}&- 0.5\end {array} \right] .
$$

Notice that due to the fact that we use THE SAME iterative scheme to define $A_i$ and $B_i$ we get very similar matrices $A_i,B_i$.
So we get for example

$$A_4:=\left[ \begin {array}{ccccc}  24.5&- 0.5&- 0.25&0&0
\\ - 0.5& 15.5&- 0.5&- 0.25&0\\ -
 0.25&- 0.5& 8.5&- 0.5&- 0.25\\ 0&- 0.25&- 0.5& 3.5&
- 0.5\\ 0&0&- 0.25&- 0.5& 0.75\end {array} \right] 
$$

with eigenvalues $$\lambda_{4,5 }:= 24.5307920815531 \quad \lambda_{4,4}:= 15.5136493593423 \quad \lambda_{4,3}:= 8.51760322347614 \quad \lambda_{4,2}:=3.54058988050425 \quad\lambda_{4,1}:=0.647365455124154$$

and

$$ B_4:= \left[ \begin {array}{cccccc}  24.5&- 0.5&- 0.25&0&0&0
\\- 0.5& 15.5&- 0.5&- 0.25&0&0\\ 
- 0.25&- 0.5& 8.5&- 0.5&- 0.25&0\\ 0&- 0.25&- 0.5&
 3.5&- 0.5&-1/4\,\sqrt {2}\\ 0&0&- 0.25&- 0.5& 0.25&
-1/2\,\sqrt {2}\\ 0&0&0&-1/4\,\sqrt {2}&-1/2\,\sqrt 
{2}&- 0.5\end {array} \right] 
$$

This matrix has the eigenvalues $$\mu_{4,1} = 0.6473654185 \quad \mu_{4,2} =3.540589910 \quad \mu_{4,3} =8.517603211 \quad \mu_{4,4} =15.51364936 \quad \mu_{4,5} =24.53079208,\mu_{4,0}=-0.9999999836$$

Obviously, the eigenvalues of $A_4$ and $B_4$ are extremely close together. Though, $B_4$ has an additional eigenvalue $\mu_{4,0}$ without a partner in the spectrum of $A_4$.

---

So what I want to do is the following:

By the iterative definition of these matrices we get sequences $(A_i)_i$ and $(B_i)_i$ with eigenvalue sequences $(\lambda_{i,1})_{i \ge 1}$,$(\lambda_{i,2})_{i \ge 1}$,$(\lambda_{i,3})_{i \ge 2}$,$(\lambda_{i,4})_{i \ge 3}$ and so on and eigenvalues $(\mu_{i,0})_{i \ge 1}$,$(\mu_{i,1})_{i \ge 1}$,$(\mu_{i,2})_{i \ge 1}$,$(\mu_{i,3})_{i \ge 2}$ and $(\mu_{i,4})_{i \ge 3}$.. .

I want to show that $\mu_{i,0} \rightarrow -1$ and all the other eigenvalues converge to their partner value, so $\lambda_{i,k} \rightarrow c_k \in \mathbb{R}$(for i approaching infinity, hence going over to larger extended matrices) and accordingly $\mu_{i,k} \rightarrow c_k.$

Numerical simulations actually suggest that this happens ( I calculated up to $A_{150}$ and $B_{150}$ where I reached a pretty good convergence to the values already strongly suggested by $A_4$ and $B_4$, but I am not able to show it.)
I will award a 300 points bounty to the person answering this question :-).

Hope my problem is clearer now!

Comment: I haven't read it all yet, but here's something to think about.... have you considered rounding errors due to the fact this is computational?

Comment: Should the $(5,5)$ element of $B_1$ be $0.25$ or $0.75$? Right now it is $0.25$.

Comment: this is indeed correct the way it is. this is also part of the 'perturbation'

Comment: You refer to recurrence relations, but you don't give any. If the entries satisfy recurrence relations, it's not surprising that the eigenvalues will show patterns.

Comment: I will edit them into the question, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Are these matrices supposed to be random or are we supposed to guess a pattern?

Comment: First, if you look at the off-diagonal elements of each row. The sum of absolute values of them for each row is pretty small. All of them is at most around $2$. It is much smaller than the typical gaps between the diagonal elements. By [Gershgorin circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), most of the eigenvalues of your matrix will be at most at a distance about $2$ from the corresponding diagonal entries and hence they are well separated. (to be cont'd)

Comment: Standard perturbation theory tell us if you have off diagonal perturbation $\alpha$ bridging two diagonal elements with a gap $\Delta$, its correction/contribution to the eigenvalues is controlled by the parameter $\frac{\alpha^2}{\Delta}$ when $|\alpha| \ll \Delta$. It will not be a surprise your eigenvalues didn't change much (at least for the portion where the diagonal entries are well separated).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you give the same names to different objects ? How can the eigenvalues of some matrix converge to anything ? numbers don't converge to things, sequences of numbers do. Also, $6+8.5 = 14.5$ and not $15.5$

Comment: @TobiasHurth I don't think so. In fact, what you want to show $\lim \mu_{i,0} \to -1$ looks a little bit strange to me, this is as if the perturbation introduced by $A \to B$ doesn't have any effect to the eigen-vectors for the operator $A_\infty$ corresponds to the limit $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} A_i$. I think the first thing one should do is figure out what are the eigenvalues/vectors for $A_{\infty}$.

Comment: @TobiasHurth I believe you, this sort of things usually happens for a reason. For the particular parameter you used for your perturbation, there should be some hidden symmetry between the original $A_\infty$ and perturbed operator $B_\infty$. I'll think about it but don't put too much hope for any result ;-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably doesn't answer the question but it might give a hint where to look for a solution. Suppose you extend a matrix $A$ by setting
$$
\widetilde A :=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0 & A\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $a$ is any real number. Of course the set of eigenvalues of $\widetilde A$ consists of $a$ plus the set of eigenvalues of $A$. So my guess is that what you observe is not really related to your choice of $a$ but more on the size of your off-diagonal elements. You have something like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a&\varepsilon\\\delta & A\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $\varepsilon^T$ is a vector with comparatively small entries and so is $\delta$. As $\varepsilon,\delta\to 0$ you will get perfect agreement and since the eigenvalues depend continuously on the entries I think you'll get an answer in that direction. But maybe I got the whole thing wrong, then I can delete that answer of course.